# solving T(n) = 8T(n/2) +Θ(n2) by substitution method

Tags: algorithm, substitution

Here's the question: 
Solve the recurrence T(n) = 8T(n/2) +Θ(n2) using substitute method. Your solution should be asymptotically tight. Show only the inductive step.

Ｉknow that for mathematical induction, we should guess the answer first(I think it might be n^3) and than prove T(n)<=c*n^3，but I have problems dealing with Θ(n2) in the function， it wil be appreciated by providing a solving process in detail,thanks a lot.

Comment: What is n2? Its n^2 or something else? This is very unclear

Comment: By substituting, parametrizing the result and with an elementary manipulation of the sums I got the result 1/2Θ(n^3) - Θ(n^2) that (should) checks. However, I'm not sure how induction could be used here. The Θ, like the other asymptotic functions, can generate or absorb constants.